# Change the product key in windows XP

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp

I want to change the product key of Windows XP SP3 machine. I found the below code, but I want in the way of a dialogue box asking for a new product key and replace the old one.

```
' 
' WMI Script - ChangeVLKey.vbs
'
' This script changes the product key on the computer
'
'***************************************************************************

ON ERROR RESUME NEXT


if Wscript.arguments.count<1 then
  Wscript.echo "Script can't run without VolumeProductKey argument"
  Wscript.echo "Correct usage: Cscript ChangeVLKey.vbs ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PRSTU-WYQZX"
  Wscript.quit
end if

Dim VOL_PROD_KEY
VOL_PROD_KEY = Wscript.arguments.Item(0)
VOL_PROD_KEY = Replace(VOL_PROD_KEY,"-","") 'remove hyphens if any

for each Obj in GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").InstancesOf("win32_WindowsProductActivation")

  result = Obj.SetProductKey (VOL_PROD_KEY)

  if err <> 0 then
    WScript.Echo Err.Description, "0x" & Hex(Err.Number)
    Err.Clear
  end if

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
VOL_PROD_KEY = Wscript.arguments.Item(0)
```

with this:

```
VOL_PROD_KEY = InputBox("Enter the new product key.")
```

Note that you should add code for handling situations where the user clicked `Cancel` or entered a malformed product key.

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^[a-z0-9]{5}(-[a-z0-9]{5}){4}$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

If IsEmpty(VOL_PROD_KEY) Then
  'user pressed Cancel
ElseIf Not re.Test(VOL_PROD_KEY) Then
  'malformed product key
Else
  'product key OK
End If
```

Comment: If i execute it shows script can,t run with out productkey argument and correct usage: Cscript ChangeVlkey.vbs ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PRSTU-WYQZX

Comment: The input validation code should go after the input. And of course you need to remove the check `if Wscript.arguments.count<1 then ... end if` if you want to run the script without arguments.